# Passing a List of Tuples to an MVC controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

The type of the object I want to handle in my controller is: List>. So basically, on the server side I have a method:

```
public void foo(List<Tuple<bool, string>> arg)
```

And on client side: I have an array of javascript objects that I fill up as shown below:

```
var _array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= checkBoxesCount; ++i) {
    var currentBool = $("input[id^='xx+" + i + "']").is(":checked");
    var currentString = $("label[id^='yy+" + i + "']").attr('stringValue');
            _array.push({
        boolValue: currentBool,
        stringValue: currentString
    });
}
```

I have checked that the boolean and strings values are read correctly on client side.

The exact error I'm getting is An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Impossible to cast a 'System.String' object into a 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'. in the JsonNetValueProviderFactory.cs file

EDIT: Ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'array': _array })
});
```

Comment: Please post what is being sent on the wire (raw HTTP request).

Comment: The code you've provided has nothing to do with the error. Please post the code snippet that causes the exception to be thrown

Comment: @zaitsman Check my last edit.

Comment: How about `_array.push({
        Value: currentBool,
        Key: currentString
    });` and then binding it to `public void foo(List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> arg)` and `data: JSON.stringify({ 'arg': _array })`

Comment: @Kikus i asked for data on the wire not the ajax call.